# Elevation shadow won't show on device only on preview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a drop shadow effect to my layout and decided to go with the elevation option.

But what I end up with in the Android Studio preview doesn't show up on the device for some reason. I will attach screenshot of Android Studio preview and device. And I will provide the code I have used.

[[image: 1]] [image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#90000000" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>


<RelativeLayout
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
    android:elevation="30dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? I've had this issue a while ago when i upgraded to Android Pie, didn't resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `elevation` property is supported only on Android 5.0+. So I think you are running your app on older device.

Here is a solution, you can use `CardView` as an alternative to `RelativeLayout`.

Add dependency in your `build.gradle`()app

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
```

Then use it in your xml file like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="300dp"
  card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
  card_view:cardElevation="30dp"
  card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
   ...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Or you can make your own shadow using `LayerList`, create a file called `shadow.xml` and place it in your `Drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--the shadow comes from here-->
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">

</item>

<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <!--whatever you want in the background, here i preferred solid white -->
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then you assign it to your view like this

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
```

Comment: yes this seems to be almost exactly what I am looking for. But Do you show how I should add an 8dp corner radius to the object with the shadow background? @Amine

Comment: You just add this attribute to the cardview `card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"`

Comment: that will just add corner radius to the cardView which is just the background, and not to the actual object inside the cardView which I want the corner radius

Comment: Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558861/how-to-get-corner-radius-on-layer-list-shadow-background